# Passing Drop down Select Value to URL

Tags: php, javascript, forms, url, drop-down-menu

```
<select id="langu" name="langu">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Chinese">中国的</option>
    <option value="Korean">한국의</option>
    <option value="Vietnamese">Việt</option>
</select>
```

The above is part of a .PHP based, based on the selection a user makes, I'd like to pass the value of the select as part of the `URL` for the form action:

```
<form name="frmLang" 
action="index2.php?r=<?php echo $rguid;?>&l=[THE DROPDOWN OPTION HERE];?>" 
method="post">
```

First off is this possible?  If so, how does one pass that variable into the URL without having to go to another page?  Javascript?  (Cannot use AJAX).

Thanks,

H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `method="post"` to `method="get"` and include `$rguid` as a hidden input:

```
<form name="frmLang" action="index2.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="r" value="<?php echo $rguid; ?>">
  <select id="langu" name="l">
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt response.  Won't bore you with the details but cannot change from 'Post' to 'Get' any other alternative?

Comment: You could add some javascript that executes `onSubmit` and rewrites your url.  Never tried, but in theory it should be possible.  Really, though, if you're `post`ing, then (in terms of proper coding) no values should go into the url at all.